# An unbound Fanout Exchange loses data

Tags: spring-boot, amqp, messagebroker, spring-rabbit

When I pass a number of messages to Fanout exchange(which is not bound to any queue,yet) and stops the publisher the messages sent to the exchange are lost. The exchange stops. Is it possible that an unbound Exchange can hold messages published?

Answer (score 1):

That's the way it's designed.

> Is it possible that an unbound Exchange can hold messages published?

Exchanges don't "hold" messages, they route them to queues.

You can set the `mandatory` flag on the sending side (and enable publisher returns) and the message will be returned to the sender if it can't be routed.